# How to visualize Point cloud?

Tags: ros, rosbag, pointcloud, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, I am new to ROS.I am using Fuerte distro. I went through the tutorials and learnt the basic commands regarding packages,nodes,publish,topic,etc using turtlesim (the means by which they were explained in the tutorial). Is there any tutorial to know about reading images(from the disk) and image processing or is it possible to read image or any data only from a bag file.

I have a bag file probably containing image & velodyne pointcloud data(found using rxbag) but i am not able to see any pointcloud. In the tutorial rviz was not clear for me. Please anyone help me with rviz and how to visualize the pointcloud from the bagfile. How to interpret the contents of the bagfile and use them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49744/how-to-visualize-point-cloud-?/) by [KARTHIK MURUGAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/3722/karthik-murugan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2012-12-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Here are the steps:

1. run rviz [rosrun rviz rviz]
2. Add display type in rviz [Add->PointCloud2] or may be just PointCloud
3. play your bag file [rosbag play abcdefg.bag]
4. Browse for the topic in the added display type in rviz

and if the point cloud is still not visible, change the display colors (because, usually it starts with white)

cheers!

---

Originally posted by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) with karma: 387 on 2012-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KARTHIK MURUGAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/3722/karthik-murugan/) on 2012-12-06**:
thank you. i tried ur suggestion. I played the bag file. i run rviz . I am able to see the image by selecting in the image topic. I cant see any pointcloud since there is no topic in the PointCloud2 list. i also tried PointCloud. But when i do rostopic list, i get /velodyne_packets...

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2012-12-06**:
try [rostopic type /velodyne_packets] to check the type. may be the bag file does not contain any PointCloud topics afterall.

**Comment by [KARTHIK MURUGAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/3722/karthik-murugan/) on 2012-12-08**:
yeah u r ryt... i had to convert that topic type to sensor_msgs/pointcloud2 topic... now i am able to select it but cant see any pointcloud... when i select the status field it shows:Transform [sender=/velodyne_pointcloud_CloudNodelet]
For frame [/velodyne]: Fixed Frame [/world] does not exist

**Comment by [KARTHIK MURUGAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/3722/karthik-murugan/) on 2012-12-08**:
yeah u r ryt... i had to convert that topic type to sensor_msgs/pointcloud2 topic... now it shows some error in fixed frame... when i select the status field it shows:Transform [sender=/velodyne_pointcloud_CloudNodelet]
For frame [/velodyne]: Fixed Frame [/world] does not exist